# Extracting MIDI data from a program

Tags: windows-10, audio, midi

I have a program (a game) that plays MIDI synthesized music in the background. In its settings, the user can choose between WAV and MIDI. This leads me to believe that Windows is doing the actual synthesizing.

I would like to capture this MIDI output into its own file. The sound data for this game *is* in its own file, but all sound data is in one .dat file, and I don't know how to sift through it. Any method of getting this is fine.

I've tried using a loopback driver (MIDI yoke), but it doesn't work (I can't see this program's output as an option in any sound setting anywhere). I'm on Windows 10. Any options?

[Here](http://www16.big.or.jp/~zun/html/th08top.html)'s a link to the webpage of the program in question (warning: Japanese).

Comment: I guess the problem is that Microsoft removed the MIDI Mapper.

Comment: Googling MIDI Mapper does seem to correlate with this issue...
Now what? Can I replace it? Or do I have to run a legacy Windows in a virtualiser?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's a program for this.

[CoolSoft MIDIMapper](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/forum/thread/427)

From what I've now read, Microsoft removed their own MIDI Mapper, so Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth was the "hardwired" MIDI player. Since there was no mapper, there was no MIDI stream to redirect/ get input from.

The above, combined with a loopback program, solves this issue. I would like to know if other programs could do this, and how it... interfaces with Windows.